# How to add class name to an array list of an object property using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the class name of each `td` and then adding another class to each `td`. For example: The current class is `class = "X-marker"` and I want to add another class `bgreen` and it should be `class = "X-marker bgreen"`.

I used `each` method to get the class name of each `td` and then used `attr` with each to set but it doesn't work. I don't get any error but it isn't working as expected.

The object is called `winInfo` and the array variable is: `winInfo.play = winArray[i];`

```
var winInfo = checkWin();
if (winInfo.win) {
    currentClass = $(winInfo.play).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('class');
    });

    $(winInfo.play).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('class', currentClass + ' bgreen');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Might look something like this:

```
$(winInfo.play).addClass('bgreen');
```

Comment: It means, I don't need to use `each` method for array list?

Comment: @MaihanNijat You shouldn't, if I'm understanding you correctly. Docs say: `Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.`

Comment: What your setting currentClass here doesn't really make sense to me. From your post it sounds like you are trying to loop over a list of TD elements and add a class to them. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just do $('X-marker').each(function() { $(this).addClass('bgreen'); }); or maybe you could try to explain the issue in more detail or provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @user3333134 What you are suggestion is actually exactly the same. jquery will run the `addClass` function on every selected elements automatically. Same goes for most jquery's methods.

Comment: @user3333134 The first class name is dynamic.

Comment: Yes but I was trying to show the use of "each"  in comparison to his post. I should of stated that better.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Hatchet, the method [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is clearly the easiest way to do it.
However, and because it seems you are misunderstanding how [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) works, here is how you could do this using `each` and without `addClass`.

I am assuming in the following that `winInfo.play` is a proper dom selector (e.g. `".class-name p"`).

```
var winInfo = checkWin();
if (winInfo.win) {
    // `each` is just a helper that will call the provided function
    // for each of the object selected by jQuery (like a loop).
    // It does not return any value.
    $(winInfo.play).each(function () {
        var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).attr('class', currentClass + ' bgreen');
    });
}
```

Oh, and because [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com), here is how you would do it in plain js.

```
var winInfo = checkWin();
if (winInfo.win) {
  // if winInfo.play is not a selector but a list of dom elements,
  // just remove document.querySelectorAll.
  for(var el of document.querySelectorAll(winInfo.play)){
    el.classList.add('bggreen');
  }
}
```